# Map a query as a virtual table

Tags: apache-calcite

Is it possible within Apache Calcite to map a JDBC based query as a virtual table?  I would like to expose a table to the user, but behind the scenes have it be implemented as a query via jdbc to a datasource.  I am aware that I can subclass Table and implement myself if necessary, but I wanted to see if there was a supported way to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a view. You can see an example in [the tutorial](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/tutorial.html#tables-and-views-in-schemas). View definitions can be added to the `model.json` you use to define your schema as in the example below.

> ```
> {
>   version: '1.0',
>   defaultSchema: 'SALES',
>   schemas: [
>     {
>       name: 'SALES',
>       type: 'custom',
>       factory: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.csv.CsvSchemaFactory',
>       operand: {
>         directory: 'target/test-classes/sales'
>       },
>       tables: [
>         {
>           name: 'FEMALE_EMPS',
>           type: 'view',
>           sql: 'SELECT * FROM emps WHERE gender = \'F\''
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```